# angular meteor - Save changes to database before changing state

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to insert a new doc into a published collection and then immediately navigate away to a different state.

The trouble is, the document is not being inserted. I'm pretty sure the subscription is being stopped before the insert gets processed. But how can I wait on the insert before changing state?

**Angular view code**

```
...
<input name="titleInput" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Project title" ng-model="newProject.title" />                                          
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="addProject()">Save</button>
```

**Controller code**

```
$scope.newProject = {};                                                                                                                                               

$meteor.subscribe('projects').then(function(subscriptionHandle) {                                                                                                     
    $scope.projects = $scope.$meteorCollection(function() {                                                                                                             
        return Projects.find({});                                                                                                                                         
    });                                                                         
});      

// Button on page calls this function
$scope.saveProject = function() {                                                                                                                                      
    $scope.newProject._id = Random.id();
    // Push data onto collection, but doesn't have chance to insert on server 
    // before change of state is fired                                                                                                                                
    $scope.projects.push($scope.newProject);
    $state.go( "projects");                                                                                                                                             
}
```

I tried using onStop callback of subscription, but the subscription still gets closed before the insert is done.

My current work-around is to call a Meteor method instead of pushing onto collection, which works OK but seems hacky - I'd like to get the above code working if possible.

Thanks...

Comment: There is nothing hacky about using meteor methods. In fact, meteor methods are far more secure (able) than pub/sub. Also, _id's are automatically assigned, try removing that. Perhaps your attempt at creating one is messing it up.

Comment: @TjGienger - Tried it without generating the _id but still no joy. Take your point about Meteor methods though. Thanks